# Programmatically modifying global custom text field in view

Tags: 7, views

I have a (Apache solr) view with a `Global: Custom text` field in addition to my normal fields. This field is meant to get value from a custom function/existing field/passing an existing field to a custom function and using return value in one of my modules per each result and I am trying to accomplish this functionality without using Views PHP module.

I referred [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84458/how-to-insert-values-into-global-custom-text-field-of-views-programmatically) very similar query and tried the following approach which did not yield me the result:

[`hook_views_pre_render`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7):

```
function mymod_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'mymodview' && $view->current_display == 'mymod_display') {
    $result = &$view->result;
    foreach ($result as $num_idx => $result_obj) {
      $result[$num_idx]->nothing = $result_obj->an_already_available_field_or_fxn_call;
    }
  }
}
```

Also tried the same code with [`hook_views_post_execute`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/7) to no avail. Using `$view->field['nothing']->options['alter']['text'] = 'My custom text';` set the default text value to all fields which was not my desired result.

Based on the post linked earlier tried the following code in my theme's template.php

[`template_preprocess_views_view_fields`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  if ($view->name != 'mymodview' && $view->current_display != 'mymod_display') {
    return;
  }
  foreach ($view->field as $id => $field) {
    $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = 'Some global custom text content';
  }
}
```

I am unable to determine what I am missing out on owing to my relative inexperience with views functionality and guidance on achieving this programatically would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use a custom handler? This way you don't need to override nothing.

Related to: [Move php in views to module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111371/move-php-in-views-to-module/111382#111382)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the value of the global text is quite simple. 
You have to use the one of the views hook.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_views_post_execute(&view)
{
   // You can change the value like this, if you have mutliple result you might want to wrap this inside a foreach loop. 
   $view->field['nothing']->options['alter']['text'] = 'updated via php';
}
```