# Move views global text field into code (attached fields and fields via relationships)

Tags: views

I have recently done away with using views php as it is unsafe. I have read a comment by @letharion whereby he mentions that adding a php directive `disable_functions = eval` is a good practice to tighten up security.

I have a problem with the views global text field:

- One cannot run php functions on fields
- It is a bit messy to have a lot of the html markup in the database
- It runs the markup through filter_xss (which is good) without giving
  one the flexibility of expanding on the allowed tags.

I have read this question: [Move php in views to module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111371/move-php-in-views-to-module/111382#111382) and would like to broaden it a bit.

I have implemented the accepted answer and it works with a slight modification:

custom.module:

```
function custom_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'custom') . '/views',
  );
}

function custom_print_my_link($nid, $type){
  return $nid . '-' . $type;
}
```

custom.views.inc:

```
function custom_views_data() {
  $data['node']['custom_stuff'] = array(
    'field' => array(
      'title' => t('Custom link'),
      'help' => t('Provide a custom content link.'),
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_node_custom_stuff',
    ),
  );
  return $data;
}
```

views_handler_field_node_link_custom_stuff:

```
class views_handler_field_node_custom_stuff extends views_handler_field_node {
  function construct() {
    parent::construct();
    $this->additional_fields['type'] = 'type';
    $this->additional_fields['nid'] = 'nid'; // this had to be added !!!
  }
  function query() {
    $this->ensure_my_table();
    $this->add_additional_fields();
  }
  function render($values) {
    $type = $this->get_value($values, 'type');
    $nid = $this->get_value($values, 'nid');
    return custom_print_my_link($nid, $type);
  }
};
```

I have set up the view with two hidden fields (nid and type) that appear before this custom field.

This works perfectly for fields attached to the node table.

**My question is:** How do I implement it for attached fields, and access the fields across relationships as well?

Comment: For what it's worth, there's [modulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/modulate) which attempts to automate this process. Not sure how well it will help, and it doesn't appear to be maintained, but it might still contain something useful for you.

Comment: CCK fields? So this is [tag:6] question?

Comment: @molot This is a Drupal 7 question, I used term CCK to describe fields that are attached to entities and not in base table.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out how to accomplish a small part of what I need done.

To add an attached field (a simple text field called 'test') I did this:

```
class views_handler_my_custom_field extends views_handler_field {
  function construct() {
    parent::construct();

    $this->additional_fields['test'] = array(
      'table' => 'field_data_field_test',
      'field' => 'field_test_value',
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * Perform any database or cache data retrieval here. In this example there is
   * none.
   */
  function query() {
    $this->ensure_my_table();
    $this->add_additional_fields();
  }

  /**
   * Render callback handler.
   *
   * Return the markup that will appear in the rendered field.
   */
  function render($values) {
    $test = $this->get_value($values, 'test');
    return $test;
  }
}
```